# Luasocket closed unexpectedly after receiving large amount of packets

Tags: unity-game-engine, tcp, lua, luasocket

I'm using luasocket tcp to receive data in non-blocking mode periodically, (settimeout(0)), after receiving large amount of packets in a very  small interval, the conn:receive(2048, part) emmit a 'closed' error.

Strangely, when I set the timeout to 0.01 the error goes away. But this is not acceptable as it would drop the frame rate of my game.

When data received is not much, the error doesn't happen.

Anyone faced/solved the problem before?